# Binding custom click events onto chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, electron

Chrome console is great and I'm looking to use it as a development environment for my app.

I would like to customize it a bit further for my specific usecase. For example in the same way that when a javascript object version of a DOM element is clicked in the console the DOM element is automatically inspected I would like to trigger a custom function in the main page.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Chrome DevTools API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) doesn't expose anything that would allow you to modify the behaviour of the Console module in an extension from my understanding.

If you need a particular behaviour *just for yourself*, you could fork the repository and play around with the code.

I spent a little while investigating as a learning task. I inspected the DevTools code by opening up DevTools in un-docked mode, and then opening another instance. I found the area in the code that handles the `click` event for the Console module.

1. In the current page, I created an object with two DOM elements, so that you can see that hovering will inspect the elements and clicking actually selects them in the Elements tab.

[image: Test objects]

2. The `_messageClicked` function in the Console module is invoked at some stage after a `click` event. I put a breakpoint there because I found `click` in the code - my best guess, since I don't know the code base at all.

[image: Inspecting DevTools 1]

3. After stepping out of this function, we find `mouseClicked` is also handling it in the Inspector module, and the `reveal` function that gets called is supposedly where it actually does the inspect logic.

You could *probably* add your own logic before this function call to invoke functions in the inspected window. The Inspector module has references to [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow).

[image: Inspecting DevTools 2]

If you can get something working here, the downside is you won't have any of the new features or updates for Chrome DevTools, so it would really just be a local modification of DevTools. If you are able to add a more general feature that is not specific to your own code, you could try suggesting it on the [Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/developers/discussion-groups) site, and possible make a pull request.

It seems like a bit of work would be involved either way.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for walking me through your process.